# PHP MYSQL insert Data into 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hey All I currently have a problem with my insert php file

I have a form.. where the user types in details.. for my form.. event name, event date and location
basically the bit that is working
is
well first of all i would like to add an entry into 2 tables: events and results

it's having no problems adding the entry into events

but it doesnt add the same entry into "results"

the events table had the following columns: Event ID, Event Name, Event Date and Location

The Results table has: Event ID, Member ID, Event Name, Score and Place

The Event ID is auto increment

so it auto assigns an ID to it

and its applied to both tables

the auto increment in Event ID

the bit thats working is

inserting entry into the events table

but because the events table and results table both have "Event Name

I want this php to fully insert details for the event table

BUT also at the same time, just insert the eventname into the results table

but the EventID in events has to be the same generated number as EventID in results..

Below is my code: All help really appreciated!!!

```
<?

        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=clubresults', 'root', '12345678');
    #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

$query = $pdo->query('SELECT EventID, EventName, EventDate, Location from events');
$rowset = array();

if ($query) {
  while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // Build array of rows
    $rowset[] = $row;
  }    

  // Output header first
  $headrow = $rowset[0];
  print("<table border=\"1\">\n<tr>\n");
  // Use $rowset[0] to write the table heading
  foreach ($headrow as $col => $val) {
    printf("<th>%s</th>\n", $col);
  }
  print("</tr>");

  // Then output table rows.
  // Outer loop iterates over row
  foreach ($rowset as $row) {
     print("<tr>");
     // Inner loop iterates over columns using $col => $val
     foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
        // We don't know your column names, but substitute the first column (the ID) for FIRSTCOL here
        printf("<td><a href=\"adminlistresults.php?EventID=%s\">%s</a></td>\n", $row['EventID'],$val);
     }
     print("</tr>");
  }
}
print("</table>");
?>
    </form>
</div>




<?

        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=clubresults', 'root', '12345678');
    #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

$stmt=$pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO events (EventName, EventDate, Location)
VALUES (:EventName, :EventDate, :Location)');


  $stmt->bindValue(':EventName', $_POST['EventName']);
  $stmt->bindValue(':EventDate', $_POST['EventDate']);
  $stmt->bindValue(':Location', $_POST['Location']);

  $stmt->execute();   



    ?>
<?
    $int_event_id = $_GET["EventID"];
    if((int)$int_event_id)
    {
$stmt=$pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO results (EventName, EventID)
VALUES (:EventResultsName, $int_event_id)');
  $stmt->bindValue(':EventName', $_POST['EventResultsName']);
      $stmt->execute();    
      }
      ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the inserts are always taking place in sequence, I'd use `$pdo->lastInsertId()` (see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

So, I think this line is wrong:

```
$int_event_id = $_GET["EventID"];
```

I'd write it like this:

```
<?
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('
              INSERT INTO results (EventName, EventID)
              VALUES (:EventResultsName, :EventId)
            ');
    $stmt->bindValue(':EventName', $_POST['EventResultsName']);
    $stmt->bindValue(':EventId', $pdo->lastInsertId());
    $stmt->execute();    
?>
```

Note that this assumes the insert into results occurs immediately after the insert into events.

You could've done the same thing without a bind variable using MySQL's native `last_insert_id()` function, like this:

```
<?
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('
              INSERT INTO results (EventName, EventID)
              VALUES (:EventResultsName, last_insert_id())
            ');
    $stmt->bindValue(':EventName', $_POST['EventResultsName']);
    $stmt->execute();    
?>
```

However, this is less portable than the previous example. However, pdo's `lastInsertId()` isn't exactly RDBMS agnostic either (see docs) so you'd have to fix this piece of code anyway if you're thinking of targeting another RDBMS

Comment: I do have 1 problem though before even starting to insert data........
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'EventName' cannot be null' in C:\xampp\htdocs\clubresults\RecordEvents.php:154 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\clubresults\RecordEvents.php(154): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\clubresults\RecordEvents.php on line 154......

Comment: well, that problem is caused by the fact that your form does not post the EventName value, or that the field is empty. Check your values before you do the inserts, and optionally add form validation so that users are enforced to supply values for the mandatory fields.

Comment: the eventName text box is empty?

Comment: Actually, it looks like there was a misspelling in your original code. For the first insert you bound EventName to `$_POST['EventName']`, but for the second insert you bound to `$_POST['EventResultsName']`. I think in both cases, it should be `$_POST['EventName']`. It does make me wonder though - why is there even an `EventName` column in the `results` table? It already links to the `events` table (via `EventID`), so it seems `results.EventName` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `Event` entity represents an event and the `Result` entity represents an outcome of an event for a particular member. So there is a 1->n relationship between `Event` -> `Result`

### Problem

This means that sometimes you will get a request where both `Event` and `Result` data needs to be inserted, while at others there will only be `Result` data. In this latter case you will be able to get EventId from the request `_GET[EventId]`.

In the first case, you will not have this `EventId` set and since you are executing the second insert based on the check `if((int)$int_event_id)`, the `Result` will never be inserted.

### Solution

The first thing you should do is check if `_GET["EventId"]` *isset*. If it **isn't** then you need to both insert an `Event` and `Result`. In this case the `EventId` will be fetched from the last inserted statement as follows:

`$pdo->lastInsertId()`

While if the `_GET["EventId"] *isset*, you should only do the second insertion as you are doing.